# In C programming, will a calculation be slower, if any variable in the expression is nan

Tags: c, nan

This is completely a hypothetical question.

In below code, I am performing calculation, which is having one variable,z , as a value assigned "nan". Will main calculation will be slower as compared to normal z value (like z = 1.0)

```
float z = 0.0/0.0; // that means z is "nan"
float p = 50.0, q = 100.0, r = 150.0;
// main calculation Type 1
float c = ((x*100)+(y*100))/(x*100)+(y*100)+152*(p+q/r)+z;
```

Here is an example to show the main calculation with normal z value

```
float z = 1.0; // normal value for z
float p = 50.0, q = 100.0, r = 150.0;
// main calculation Type 2
float c = ((x*100)+(y*100))/(x*100)+(y*100)+152*(p+q/r)+z;
```

Hence, which one is slower, Type 1 or Type 2? Or there will be no time difference?
In single calculation, time difference might not be visible, but, if we collect millions of such equations, how time results will vary?

Any kind of thought, logic or information will be appreciated.

Note: Currently i am not concerned about the result value of variable 'c';

Comment: Why don't you attempt to time it?

Comment: actually i am getting time difference.. but i want to make sure, it is because of this.. Is there a possibility?

Comment: If more hypothetically i think, equation with a nan should be more faster, because it doesn't has to actually calculate the result and has to return 'nan' as a final answer.

Comment: Why not taking a look at the disassembly?

Comment: Do you have optimisations enabled? If so, I would expect the NAN case to be faster.

Comment: yes they are enabled..  gcc -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -O2 -finline-functions @KevinA.Naudé

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the CPU. Old x86 intel chips, without SSE, handled NAN very badly (see http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/x86andinfinity.html for a 10-year-old analysis.) However, SSE2/3/4 doesn't suffer from this problem, and I don't believe AMD ever did.

You may well see this problem on modern chips if you tell your compiler to avoid SSE instructions for possible compatibility (but that will definitely slow down floating point regardless of NaNs, so don't do it unless you have to.) As far as I know, this compatibility mode is still the gcc default for x86 builds.

I don't know about ARM floating point units; you'd have to test.

I suspect that NANs are not the issue that they were a decade ago, but enough people have a vague memory of those times that the prejudice undoubtedly will live on for a while longer.

Comment: so @rici are you suggesting, there "MIGHT BE" (or might not be) chances time may differ because of nan??

Comment: @Vishwadeep: I'm not suggesting that. I'm saying it. If you have old 586 CPUs, they'll slow down with NaNs.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. i will scope more

Comment: @rici I've written many codes where enabling SSE instructions in the compilation slows the program down - sometimes considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking critically is really making me challenge my understanding of C. I think the best answer is to experiment. Use time.h to save the clock time before and after each calculation and compute the difference.

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<time.h> 
clock_t t1, t2;
float result;

t1 = clock();
//perform calculation1
t2 = clock();
printf("%f", result);

t1 = clock();
//perform calculation2
t2 = clock();
printf("%f", result);
```

Comment: The `clock` function is not useful for this. Its resolution is so poor you'd have to do millions of calculations (and avoid having the compiler decide to optimize them all out because the result is unused or constant), and even then, its implementations is often buggy.

Comment: My bad! Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

On some RISC architectures such as [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Floating_point), the floating point unit is designed to handle the common case as fast as possible. The floating point unit traps when it encounters a NaN, then the rest of the calculation is handled using a software IEEE floating point emulator. So calculating with NaNs will be much slower on such an architecture.  AFAIK this is not true for the Intel x86 architecture.

Answer (score -1):

There wont be any difference.

At the low level, computer just assigns the value. Doesn't check what was in there before.

Calculations' assembly codes must be the same.

If you check the whole code, first program must be slower because you make an extra calculation in it. (0.0/0.0).

Comment: same way i am thinking.

Comment: This is not true in general.  Values like `NaN` are special, and can concievably cause CPU operations involving them not to execute through the fast path but trap to a much slower microcoded implementation.

Comment: The computer is not just assigning a value, it is doing floating point arithmetic, so it must interpret the values and not just copy them.

Comment: In its assembly code, when every calculation finished and the result is in AC, it just calls MVI. So this command do nothing with the previous value. It just moves the AC value immediately. Do you even know assembly language ?